# Space getting consumed during regex

Tags: java, regex

Using regex to pull out words with length of 5 with space before and after. Thus all the following words should match my pattern. But it seems after matching the first word, the space is consumed which makes the second word fail the match.

To illustrate, I should/ want to get the printout as:

**apple orange pines dorms**

Instead, I get:

**apple pines**

How can I handle this issue?

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myStr = " apple orange pines dorms ";
    regexChecker("(\\s[A-Za-z]{5}\\s)", myStr);
}

public static void regexChecker(String regex, String strToCheckOn){

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strToCheckOn);

    while (m.find()){
        if(m.group().length() != 0){
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookahead and lookbehind instead of consuming spaces before/after words:

```
(?<=\\s|^)[A-Za-z]{5,}(?=\\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM2sI4/1)

- `(?<=\\s|^)` is lookbehind that asserts we have line start or a whitespace before our match
- `(?=\\s|$)` is lookahead that asserts we have line end or a whitespace after our match